# Как сделать JSONArray рабочим в цикле for-each?

Tags: java, json, foreach

Интересно, как можно написать свой `JSONArray`, чтобы его `JSONObject`'ы можно было пробегать через цикл for-each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Java это сделать довольно просто:

Создать декоратор над JSONArray:

```
public class ExtendedJSONArray implements Iterable<JSONObject> {

    private final JSONArray jsonArray;

    public ExtendedJSONArray(JSONArray jsonArray) {
        this.jsonArray = jsonArray;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<JSONObject> iterator() {
        return new ExtendedJSONArrayIterator();
    }

    private class ExtendedJSONArrayIterator implements Iterator<JSONObject> {

        private int iterator;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return iterator < jsonArray.length();
        }

        @Override
        public JSONObject next() {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(iterator);
            iterator++;
            return jsonObject;
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            jsonArray.remove(iterator);
        }
    }
}
```

Далее можно использовать так:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
jsonArray.put(new JSONObject("{\"a\":5,\"b\":10}"));
jsonArray.put(new JSONObject("{\"a\":15,\"b\":20}"));
jsonArray.put(new JSONObject("{\"a\":25,\"b\":30}"));

for (JSONObject jsonObject: new ExtendedJSONArray(jsonArray)) {
    System.out.println(jsonObject.toString(2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

На Kotlin проще всего JSONArray перевести в Array и гонять любыми циклами.

Либо так по индексу:

```
val jsonArray = JSONArray()
for (i in Array(jsonArray.length()) { i -> i }) {
    val item = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
    // ...
}
```

Либо так:

```
val jsonArray = JSONArray()
for (item in Array(jsonArray.length()) { i -> jsonArray.getJSONObject(i) }) {
    // ...
}
```

Соответсвенно, все функциональные примочки (forEach, filter, first, ...) тоже будут доступны.